# Rationalize complex numbers

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

What is the best way to rationalize complex numbers, if not both the real and imaginary part are actually rational?

According to the documentation, `Rationalize` works on complex numbers, but apparently only when both the real and the imaginary part can be rationalized, for example

```
Rationalize[N[4/3 + I 2/3]]
(*4/3 + I 2/3*)
```

However, `Rationalize[N[4/3 + I Sqrt[2]/3]]` is not simplified, whereas I would like it to return `4/3 + I 0.471405`.

Thanks.

Comment: Seeing as `4/3 + I N[ Sqrt[2]/3]` is immediately and automatically converted to `1.33333 + 0.471405 I`, I don't see how it can be done.

Comment: Thanks for this observation. I suppose, using `HoldForm` will do for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the exact output you requested but in case you are not aware of the second parameter of [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html):

```
Rationalize[N[4/3 + I Sqrt[2]/3], 1*^-6]
```

> ```
> 4/3 + (272 I)/577
> ```

If your hybrid output really is desired then perhaps building on m_goldberg's deleted answer:

```
# + Defer[#2 I] & @@ Rationalize /@ {Re@#, Im@#} & @ N[4/3 + I Sqrt[2]/3]
```

> ```
> 4/3 + 0.471405 I
> ```